# Why do AxWindows Media Players affect Full Screen Generation in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm using many AxWindows Media Players (AxWMPLib) to play sound in my piano application on Visual Studio. I'm not using them for video, and so they are all invisible. I also want to play my application in full screen mode. The full screen mode works fine with no media players, all the anchors work correctly as I want. [This is the full screen without the Media Players and it is all good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctSXz.png)

However, as soon as I add one media player, [it then looks like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB8YD.png) The anchors break and the full screen mode completely alters? I don't know why this happens, and I am really stuck as to why adding an AxWMPLib breaks the anchors like this, without altering the AxWMPLib at all.

Does anyone know why this is the case and how to fix it?
Thank you in advance :D

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228185/how-to-configure-an-app-to-run-correctly-on-a-machine-with-a-high-dpi-setting-e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to this problem! I hope my solution below will help anyone in the future. If you are using AxWMPLib and want the form to be fullscreen, all the elements might not anchor correctly, and stay in the top left corner of the screen (like the screenshots in the question).

I found this to be caused by the WindowState Property in the Layouts section. Rather than setting the WindowState Property as **Maximised**, keep it as **Normal**, and then change the WindowState Property programmaticly in the `Form_Load` Sub, with the following code:

```
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximised
```

And then hopefully when you run the form, the form will still be fullscreen but the AxWMPLib won't cause it to go wrong, and everything should be anchored correctly.